# Cannot mkdir /data/db (or sudo mkdir /data/db) for mongodb. Haven't been able to find an answer here that works

Tags: database, mongodb, mkdir

I get this when I run mongod -

```
Johns-MacBook-Pro:~ johnnyringo506$ mongod
2020-02-18T17:12:06.439-0500 I  CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2020-02-18T17:12:06.446-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=24840 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=Johns-MacBook-Pro.local
2020-02-18T17:12:06.446-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.2.3
2020-02-18T17:12:06.446-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 6874650b362138df74be53d366bbefc321ea32d4
2020-02-18T17:12:06.446-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2020-02-18T17:12:06.446-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2020-02-18T17:12:06.446-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2020-02-18T17:12:06.446-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2020-02-18T17:12:06.446-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2020-02-18T17:12:06.446-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2020-02-18T17:12:06.447-0500 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found., terminating
2020-02-18T17:12:06.447-0500 I  NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2020-02-18T17:12:06.447-0500 I  -        [initandlisten] Stopping further Flow Control ticket acquisitions.
2020-02-18T17:12:06.447-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2020-02-18T17:12:06.447-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

And then I receive a "mkdir: /data: No such file or directory" when I try to create it

Answer (score 0):

Try to run with sudo, the issue might be with permissions
or create directory with this command sudo mkdir -p /data/db then restart MongoDB service

Comment: when I did that, I received mkdir: /data/db: Read-only file system

Comment: Have you tried creating the directory first with sudo mkdir -p /data/db then restarting MongoDB with sudo systemctl restart MongoDB

Comment: Same thing - mkdir: /data/db: Read-only file system. And sudo: systemctl command not found on the other

Comment: sudo chmod 0755 /data/db and sudo chown -R $USER /data/db
follow this link https://www.demainilpleut.fr/dealing-with-the-mongodb-error-datadb-not-found-in-osx/

Comment: I'm confused here. How can I change permissions if the file or directory doesn't exist? (I tried all of this just in case I wasn't seeing something and it still didn't work)